# When was the dynamic array first introduced as an example for amortized analysis?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, reference-request, arrays, amortized-analysis

I'm writing a report on amortized analysis, and I'm using the example of a dynamic array to explain each method. I think it would be nice to add a reference to when this example was first used, as it seems like it is a classic example.

I've been looking and can't seem to find a reference to it. Does anyone know when the example was first used?